# Writing a SQLite database trigger to hide specific data from SELECT requests

Tags: sqlite, stored-procedures, triggers

Is it possible to write a SQLite trigger and/or stored procedure that would return alternate data in a SELECT request if the data is not recent? I know how this could be done when selecting a specific record, because then the record ID could be passed to a stored procedure for evaluation. But I want a `SELECT * FROM TABLE` statement to obscure only relevant data, regardless of the conditions specified in a subsequent `WHERE` clause. Each individual record must be evaluated. This could be accomplished by modifying the existing data or by simply returning a false value. For instance, something like this pseudocode:

```
for (RECORD in ALL_RECORDS_REQUESTED) {

  // test if field contains value of interest and is more than one hour old
  if ( ( fieldOfInterest LIKE '%VALUE_I_AM_CENSORING%' ) && ( recordTimestamp > ( recordTimestamp + 60 ) ) ) {

    // change value of field before returning (or simply return false value)
    fieldOfInterest = 'value I want you to see';

  }

}
```

Suffice is to say that I do not want a trigger to modify any data when it is initially INSERTED or UPDATED in the table, as I want the original value to be available for at least one hour. After that I want it to be changed if any `SELECT` statements request the record(s).

Is this possible in SQLite or would this require modifying the application that interacts with the database? I am aware of how to code this within the application but would prefer to handle this within the database itself.

This could also be accomplished by a trigger that automatically appends a condition to every SQL statement, allowing the exclusion of data: 
    `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT fieldOfInterest, recordTimestamp 
    FROM tblOfInterest 
      WHERE fieldOfInterest LIKE '%VALUE_I_AM_CENSORING%' 
        AND recordTimestamp > recordTimestamp + 60)`

Or something to this effect....

Answer (score 2):

[Triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) only fire whenever a `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` of a particular database table occurs, or whenever an `UPDATE` occurs on on one or more specified columns of a table.

You could use a [`VIEW`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) to accomplish what you want, but then all data access would have to go through that view.